# My root directory is not opening in wsl

Tags: 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am getting the following error in windows subsystem for linux.

```
surface@Surface:~$ sudo -i
sudo: /bin/zsh: command not found
surface@Surface:~$
```

Comment: You messed up your PATH variable. Check with `echo $PATH` if `/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:` are part of it. Do you have  a `source ~/.bash_profile`  in your `./zsh` ?

Comment: @Rinzwind since `/bin/zsh` is absolute, why would `PATH` be involved? I think it's more likely that the OP has set root's login shell to `/bin/zsh` but `/bin/zsh` doesn't exist on their system